# spark scala create column from Dataframe with values dependent on date time range

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to create a new column from a dataframe that lets say looks like

```
names|birthtime-datetime|
joe|2017-03-29 2:23:38|
mike|2017-03-29 3:53:38|
mary|2017-03-29 11:63:38|
.....
```

I want to add a column that based on if the DateTime column is in a range gets a int. let's say in this case there are 3 categories. born before 5:31am but after 1am, born after 5am, but before 10 am, born after 10am.
the first getting a 1, the second a 2, the third a 3. so the data should look like

```
names|birthtime-datetime|NewCol|
joe|2017-03-29 2:23:38|1|
mike|2017-03-29 3:53:38|1|
mary|2017-03-29 11:63:38|3|
.....
```

I would rather not use a UDF, but I'm open to a UDF. I'm using scala. One thought had was to per group filter based on time range, add the new column, and then merge back .. one for each group. that seems like a really dumb idea.. but I had it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve what you want with the `hour` function from the [`functions` class](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$) (the place where most of the functions are, along with the Column class), and by chaining a few `when` / `otherwise`.

```scala
// let's create data
val df = Seq(("joe", "2017-03-29 2:23:38"), 
             ("mike", "2017-03-29 3:53:38"),
             ("mary", "2017-03-29 11:03:38"))
        .toDF("name", "date")
        .select('name, to_timestamp('date) as "date")

// Then, let's extract the hour and add your logic
// (I'm not sure it is your exact logic, but you see the idea)
df.withColumn("h", hour('date))
  .withColumn("int", when('h >= 1 && 'h < 5, 1)
                      .otherwise(when('h >= 5 && 'h < 10, 2)
                        .otherwise(3)))
  .show
+----+-------------------+---+---+
|name|               date|  h|int|
+----+-------------------+---+---+
| joe|2017-03-29 02:23:38|  2|  1|
|mike|2017-03-29 03:53:38|  3|  1|
|mary|2017-03-29 11:03:38| 11|  3|
+----+-------------------+---+---+
```

Comment: is thier an easy way to do this if I want to do let's say 5:31am to 7:42am? I could break them out to separate column but it would be easier to use a time comparison

Comment: With a datetime type you should be able to do col("Foo").between(bar, baz)

Comment: @Brian What version of spark are you using? As of spark 2.3, there is a `date_trunc` function that could help you. @Jesse unfortunately that would not work because what brian wants should only depend on the time of the day, and not on the entire date.

Comment: @Oli I'll give that a try and see if It works. I care actually in some cases the day of the month, some cases the day of the week, and in some cases the time (H & M). I could do a UDF and mess with joda but I would assume that's going to slow things down and in my case with larger data that's ideally something I want to avoid.

Comment: so the @Oli, your first idea seems the most helpful. What I'm thinking now is don't split hour and min but simply have a column that is all the same date, but the time is not touched. I'm looking at that now.

Comment: Don't hesitate to check out the various functions available, there is a date functions category with a lot of nice stuff.

Comment: so I went with a UDF, I have way more time slots than I let on initially. Sadly its very slow, but I'm not sure its the udf it could just be the size of my data.